# ASP.Net authentication: Can I have multiple responses when user fails to authenticate/authorize to access a page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am using ASP.net form authentication for my web application. I have folder "admin" for administration work, and also I can lock one user if he/she misbehaves.

currently if an normal user tries to access the admin page, it will be redirected to the logon page, although he/she is already logged on.

The question is: **how can I configure the web app, so that when the user fails to access a page, I can show different pages such as "you need admin privilege to access this page"/"your account is locked out"/(normal logon page)**?

ValidateUser() can only return bool. :(

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement roles and add people to them. Once you assign people to the proper roles, you would check to see if the person is in the proper role to access a page. If not, redirect them or show the proper error message. You would be able to do this with code behind like it seems like you are already trying:

```
if(!Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")) Response.Redirect("~/");
```

Or you can use the web.config

```
<configuration>
   <location path="memberPages">
       <system.web>
            <authorization>
               <allow roles="Administrator" />
               <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
          </system.web>
        </location>
<configuration>
```

See the links below for more info:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083524/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121405-1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx

Comment: I see. So in that case I need to check the returnUrl to see which directory the user is attempting to access and then check the corresponding role(s), right? I don't quite like checking in this way but I did not find any alternative so far.

Comment: Kinda, yeah. You can make it nicer by putting the logging in a base page, a master page or even a HttpModule. If you go the HttpModule route, you may want to look into the `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method and the `HttpApplication`'s `AuthenticateRequest` or `AuthorizeRequest` events.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this kind of problem giving different urls to diffenrent roles.

To admin you give www.yoursite.com/admin
to user you give www.yoursite.com/private

asp.net will automatically redirect both to the login.aspx page but you can get from the url parameter which kind of user it is.

```
//I detect where the request originated from
    string str = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null ? "" : Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString();
        //if this is Admin can access to Admin Area only
        if (str.Contains("Admin") == true || str.Contains("admin") == true || str.Contains("ADMIN") == true)
            { .......
```

Comment: This isn't secure. The user can tamper with the URL and gain access.

Comment: well I omitted the remaining of my code! it's obvious that after that you check user credentials!! I suggested to add this code on top of user credential check to route different roles to different site zones as required from the original question

Comment: If you check that the user is authorized after checking the Url I don't really see the point of the parameter. You have to make sure that the user actually is an administrator.